Difficulty with read_graphml function from the Boost Graph library
I am trying to use the read_graphml function from the Boost library to read some .graphml files in a C++ application that I am developing. However, I am running into unexpected difficulties in reading properties. Here is a MWE of my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/graph/graphml.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/dynamic_property_map.hpp>

using namespace boost;

int main(int, char**){

    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, setS, undirectedS> Graph;


    std::ifstream graph_file;
    graph_file.open("more_exampleHoles_8.graphml", std::ifstream::in);

    Graph g;
    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    boost::read_graphml(graph_file, g, dp);
}

Here is the contents of more_exampleHoles_8.graphml:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- created by IGraph/M, http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM -->
<graphml xmlns='http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns'
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xsi:schemaLocation='http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd'>
 <key id="v_betti"
     for="node"
     attr.name="betti"
     attr.type="long" />
 <key for='node'
     id='v_dimk'
     attr.name='dimk'
     attr.type='long' />
 <key for='node'
     id='v_gap'
     attr.name='gap'
     attr.type='double' />
 <graph id='Graph'
     edgedefault='undirected'>
  <node id="1">
   <data key="v_betti">5</data>
   <data key='v_dimk'>1</data>
   <data key='v_gap'>0.12405641442417092</data>
  </node>
  <node id='2' />
  <node id='3' />
  <node id='4' />
  <node id='5' />
  <node id='6' />
  <node id='7' />
  <node id='8' />
  <node id='9' />
  <node id='10' />
  <node id='11' />
  <node id='12' />
  <edge source='1'
      target='2' />
  <edge source='1'
      target='3' />
  <edge source='1'
      target='4' />
  <edge source='1'
      target='8' />
  <edge source='2'
      target='7' />
  <edge source='2'
      target='9' />
  <edge source='2'
      target='11' />
  <edge source='3'
      target='5' />
  <edge source='3'
      target='10' />
  <edge source='4'
      target='5' />
  <edge source='4'
      target='6' />
  <edge source='4'
      target='7' />
  <edge source='4'
      target='8' />
  <edge source='4'
      target='9' />
  <edge source='4'
      target='11' />
  <edge source='5'
      target='9' />
  <edge source='5'
      target='10' />
  <edge source='6'
      target='8' />
  <edge source='7'
      target='10' />
  <edge source='8'
      target='10' />
  <edge source='9'
      target='11' />
 </graph>
</graphml>

When running the code, I receive the following output:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::property_not_found>'
  what():  Property not found: betti.
Aborted (core dumped)

I am pretty confident that the graphml is well formed, so this seems to me to be a bug with the read_graphml function. If I remove the following lines from the .graphml file, everything works fine, but of course I don't want to remove these lines.
   <data key="v_betti">5</data>
   <data key='v_dimk'>1</data>
   <data key='v_gap'>0.12405641442417092</data>


That's not a MWE. Start by defining what Graph is?

Boost expects you to define property maps for all properties present. If you want to ignore unknown properties, add the filter to the dynamic properties constructor:
boost::dynamic_properties dp(boost::ignore_other_properties);

Alternatively, add the property maps:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/graph/graphml.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/dynamic_property_map.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct VertexProps {
    long   betti, dimk;
    double gap;
};
using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::undirectedS, VertexProps>;

int main() {
    std::ifstream graph_file("more_exampleHoles_8.graphml");
    Graph         g;

    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("betti", get(&VertexProps::betti,   g));
    dp.property("dimk",  get(&VertexProps::dimk,    g));
    dp.property("gap",   get(&VertexProps::gap,     g));
    read_graphml(graph_file, g, dp);
}


added the alternative showing how to consume the properties

Thanks for that, I really don't feel the Boost documentation made this clear

In case anyone lands on this page in the future, @sehe's code above resulted in compiler errors for me. Perhaps it requires C++ 20? However, an example of setting up property maps can be found here that worked for me.

The complexity is caused by the genericity. I honestly think that is at odds with usability or good documentation, as it is a common problem with all generic libraries (rangev3, libfmt, CGAL). Many Boost libraries fit in this category. It typically means the learning curve is steep and you really can only stay to be productive when you've read through an the concepts and understand their function in the algorithms you need. In all fairness only examples help but they often don't make the subtler details stand out, so naive changes break things. Believe me I've learned the same way.

Sorry for the follow up question in the comments, but how do I get my properties out of this map?

Re: C++11: it compiles in c++11 (I fixed a problem in the test XML which had broken newlines)

Thanks, I've managed to get it to compile, but I am struggling to read the properties out again. I have tried, get(&VertexProps::betti, g, 0), but that doesn't compile.

I've also tried g[0].betti, which compiles but results in a core dump.

Please do check documentation. g[0] compiles, but 0 is an invalid vertex descriptor! It would have worked for vecS as the container selector. Here's some inspiration (the last parts use some c++17 convenience): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91b9df55d14c5c86

Just compare with vecS: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03fb0937faaafc29
